# Ground state interparticle distance in a system of interacting particles under harmonic confinement

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, ground-state

Let us consider a system of two particles interacting via Coulomb force and being acted upon by a global harmonic oscillator potential. So, the system Hamiltonian is,
$$H=\sum_{i=1}^{2}\frac{p_i^2}{2m}+\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r_{12}} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2}m\omega^2 r_i^2.$$

Let us say that the ground state inter-particle distance is $r_0$. Then $r_0$ can be expressed as (see for example, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.113401 ) ,
$$r_0=\Big(\frac{2q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 m \omega^2}\Big)^{1/3}.$$
I can see that it is obtained by eqating Coulomb interaction to harmonic oscillator potential at $r_0$ in the ground state,
$$\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_{0}}=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 r_0^2.$$

But I dont understand why the above equality holds in the ground state ? I mean, what is the origin of the above equality ? Why are they not equal in excited state ? Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: You should probably clarify your notation here, as it is not altogether clear how this harmonic potential is acting (does it pull both particles near a single point? Does it pull them to some characteristic distance from each other?) Also a small thing, but your $r_{ij}$ being in the sum means you actually have a duplicate of your Coulomb interaction potential in the equation.

Comment: @MattHanson I have now edited the Hamiltonian. Since, the zero of the harmonic oscillator potential is at $r_i=0$, it is pulling the particles towards $r_i=0$.

Comment: @MattHanson Is it now clear ?

Comment: I’m still unclear about the definition of your coordinates in the harmonic oscillator. Is it with respect to the inter-particle distance, or the absolute coordinates of the space they are in?

Comment: The coordinates in harmonic oscillator potential are absolute coordinates i.e, with respect to the origin of the system of two particles. Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Comment: I am not getting how  the coordinates can be measured with respect to the interparticle distance.  Can you give an example ? Is it meaningful to choose the harmonic oscillator coordinates in this fashion ?

Answer (score 1):

In that paper you link to they consider the strongly-correlated limit. For your case of the Hooke's atom (two Coulomb-interacting electrons with Harmonic potential) this limit corresponds to taking $\omega \to 0$ and it is essentially the limit where the effects of the interaction dominate over the kinetic energy contribution. The perturbative expansion for the energy in the strongly-correlated limit is in powers of $\omega^{1/3}$ and once this series is known the remaining energy components (electronic interaction included) can be generated from the Hellmann-Feynman theorem.

The real explanation of why this relationship should be a little bit natural is that in this limit we are essentially computing a perturbation theory from a limit where we have no kinetic energy/ the electrons are infinitely interacting. To generate the correct form of the perturbative expansion we consider the total potential energy (interaction plus confinement) about the classical equilibrium position (the location where the two-electrons would settle if they were infinitely repelling, but confined). We then consider this potential order-by-order in the quantum problem to generate all terms in the strongly-correlated ($\omega \to 0$) limit.

To leading order in $\omega^{1/3}$ it is equivalent to the classical result that you have.

This paper is a very detailed breakdown of this system and what I mention:
https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/113/19/8434/850297/The-ground-state-of-harmonium

Comment: Can you explain to me how does strongly correlated limit correspond to $\omega\to 0$ ?

Comment: If you rewrite the eigenvalue problem in terms of $x=\sqrt{\omega}r$ and divide through by omega we have that $\hat{T}\Psi + V_{ee}\Psi/\sqrt{\omega} + V_{ext}\Psi/\omega = (E/\omega)\Psi$, and thus as $\omega \to 0$ the interaction term dominates over the kinetic energy in this limit. Normally this is the starting point to compute the perturbation theory in the weakly-correlated limit of $\omega \to \infty$ (where the interaction is small compared to the kinetic energy).